# Road sign recognition

Tags: c++, opencv, image-recognition, sift, orb

Currently I am stuck with a problem inside the project I am working on. The project is a road sign recognition system. And a.t.m. it can detect the road signs and, almost, recognize them, but here I got one problem.

**Problem**

The problem is with the recognition of speed signs. The recognizer of those signs, can’t separate the numbers inside a speed sign. So if it is a 80 sign it get matched as a 70 sign, because the sign is almost identical.

[Link with images for recognition](https://mrc11.stackstorage.com/s/hJrGGoTcpgcCN8t)

- "Saved" - folder are my input images
- "Matching_images" - folder are my matching images

**What I tried so far:**

a) "Multi Cascade Classifier": I trained several Cascade Classifiers, each on a particular speed limit class, e.g. one for the 50s, on the 60s and so on. This worked somehow but performance was bad.
Main problems:

```
• 30 and 80 signs (and others as well) got confused. 
• I am not able to tell if my ROI shows is a speed limit at all.
```

b) "Features2D": I tried feature based classifiers, "ORB followed by brute-force-hamming/ FLANN" and "SIFT followed by brute force/FLANN" and "AKAZE, SURF".

```
• signs still got confused 
• no possibility to reject "non speed limit" signs
```

c ) “OCR”: I tried to read the characters in the sign with the [OCR example from OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/text/samples/end_to_end_recognition.cpp), but this can’t read the sign, because, I believe, the images are to low quality.

D ) “Image matching”: This just doesn’t working properly, but maybe because I don’t know how this worked. Tested with this [test code](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html).

E ) “FindContours with OCR”: FindContours did work on one specific image, but then the ‘8’ got matched with the ‘3’, so the speed sign was a 30 sign instead of a 80 sign.

I don’t want to use a CNN for this solution, because I think it is overkill, because I only need to read a small numbers.

**Question:**

- How can I read the characters in a road sign to separate a 70 sign from a 80 sign etc…
- How can I know [this](https://mrc11.stackstorage.com/s/YMU0BfrRObqZbCR) is a 80 sign, instead of a 70 sign. (Can't post images...)

Thank you in advance,

Maurice

Comment: The state of the art on this kind of problems is given by Convolutional Neural Networks. You just need some more data for training. For example you could check [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/traffic-sign-recognition/data). I don't think a CNN in overkill since you can tune the size of the network to the specific needs of your project.

Comment: Is CNN the only solution for this small problem? Don't have the knowledge of CNN and don't have the time to learn how to use a CNN.

Comment: You can try to extract SIFT/SURF features and learn an SVM on them but the result depends on the size of the dataset. As an alternative you can use a better OCR service like the one from [Google](https://cloud.google.com/vision/). Even [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) should be able to give you good results.